# Sum columns of a Spark dataframe and create another dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, sum

I have a dataframe like below -

[image]

I am trying to create another dataframe from this which has 2 columns - the column name and the sum of values in each column like this -

[image]

So far, I've tried this (in Spark 2.2.0) but throws a stack trace -

```
val get_count: (String => Long) = (c: String) => {
    df.groupBy("id")
      .agg(sum(c) as "s")
      .select("s")
      .collect()(0)
      .getLong(0)
}
val sqlfunc = udf(get_count)

summary = summary.withColumn("sum_of_column", sqlfunc(col("c")))
```

Are there any other alternatives of accomplishing this task?

Comment: instead of screenshot, copy your test dataframe

Answer (score 2):

I think that the most efficient way is to do an aggregation and then build a new dataframe. That way you avoid a costly `explode`.

First, let's create the dataframe. BTW, it's always nice to provide the code to do it when you ask a question. This way we can reproduce your problem in seconds.

```
val df = Seq((1, 1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 5, 0, 0),
             (0, 1, 0, 6, 0), (0, 1, 0, 4, 3))
    .toDF("output_label", "ID", "C1", "C2", "C3")
```

Then we build the list of columns that we are interested in, the aggregations, and compute the result.

```
val cols = (1 to 3).map(i => s"C$i")
val aggs = cols.map(name => sum(col(name)).as(name))
val agg_df = df.agg(aggs.head, aggs.tail :_*) // See the note below
agg_df.show
+---+---+---+
| C1| C2| C3|
+---+---+---+
|  5| 10|  4|
+---+---+---+
```

We almost have what we need, we just need to collect the data and build a new dataframe:

```
val agg_row = agg_df.first
cols.map(name => name -> agg_row.getAs[Long](name))
    .toDF("column", "sum")
    .show
+------+---+
|column|sum|
+------+---+
|    C1|  5|
|    C2| 10|
|    C3|  4|
+------+---+
```

EDIT:

NB: `df.agg(aggs.head, aggs.tail :_*)` may seem strange. The idea is simply to compute all the aggregations computed in `aggs`. One would expect something more simple like `df.agg(aggs : _*)`. Yet the signature of the `agg` method is as follows:

```scala
def agg(expr: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exprs: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)
```

maybe to ensure that at least one column is used, and this is why you need to split `aggs` in `aggs.head` and `aggs.tail`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will provide code rather than screenshots the next time i ask a question. Can you help me understand why do you `val agg_df = df.agg(aggs.head, aggs.tail :_*)`. 

Also, you need to edit your answer to modify `val cols = (1 until 3).map(i => s"C$i")` to `val cols = (1 until 4).map(i => s"C$i")` so that you loop through all the C1 to C3 columns

Answer (score 1):

What i do is to define a method to create a struct from the desired values:

```
  def kv (columnsToTranspose: Array[String]) = explode(array(columnsToTranspose.map {
    c => struct(lit(c).alias("k"), col(c).alias("v"))
  }: _*))
```

This functions receives a list of columns to transpose (your 3 last columns in your case) and transform them in a struct with the column name as key and the column value as value

And then use that method to create an struct and process it as you want

```
df.withColumn("kv", kv(df.columns.tail.tail))
.select( $"kv.k".as("column"), $"kv.v".alias("values"))
.groupBy("column")
.agg(sum("values").as("sum"))
```

First apply the previous defined function to have the desired columns as the said struct, and then deconstruct the struct to have a column key and a column value in each row.
Then you can aggregate by the column name and sum the values

**INPUT**

```
+------------+---+---+---+---+
|output_label| id| c1| c2| c3|
+------------+---+---+---+---+
|           1|  1|  0|  0|  1|
|           1|  1|  5|  0|  0|
|           0|  1|  0|  6|  0|
|           0|  1|  0|  4|  3|
+------------+---+---+---+---+
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+------+---+
|column|sum|
+------+---+
|    c1|  5|
|    c3|  4|
|    c2| 10|
+------+---+
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly fine for few columns. It's just that I have more than 30k C type columns (apologies for not specifying in the question upfront) and the explode fails for that many columns. Looking to see if answer suggested by +Oli works.

Comment: I'm running this in spark-shell so it's a bit difficult to post the entire error as it's a pretty long stack trace, but error appears similar to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19984